# Save the session even if the app is killed Objective C

Tags: objective-c, session, save, nsuserdefaults

I'm developing an app in Objective C and everything is cool but i am really new in this, so i was wondering if there is a way to save the session from a user that has already logged in into my app, I save the username + password cause I use them later but when i close the app, (kill it), i have to log in again, so i was hoping that you guys could help me with this:

Here is how i save the session in my code:

```
NSString *user = [textUser text];
NSString *password = [textPassword text];


[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:user forKey:@"userName"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:password forKey:@"userPassword"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];//here is where i save the user info but i want it to stay even if the app is killed
```

So what i think i need is a method that checks if NSUserDefaults is empty or not, then go straight to my home-screen-activity

Thanks!

Comment: Great, Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, whether I understood your Q correctly!? Do you want to know how to check, whether there are already log-in data?

```
NSString *user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userName"];
if (user)
{
  // User name already has been stored
  …
}
else
{
  // User name is not stored
}
```

Comment: I want it to check if there is a already logged in user, and if so that my app goes to my main screen

Comment: Both of your codes actually solved the problem, thank you very much! @AminNegm-Awad

Answer (score 1):

Use this Method to check login:

method returns `YES` if user already logged in else returns `NO`.

```
-(BOOL)CheckLogin{

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"userName"] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"userPassword"]) {

        //go straight to my home-screen-activity

        return YES;
    }
    else{

        //required to login
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: An unset key in the user defaults as in any dictionary return `nil`, not `@""`.